# Can a landlord raise the rent as much as it want as long as it gets permission from the board?

Tags: canada, rent

> When can a landlord raise the rent above the guidelines?
>
> A landlord can make an application to the Board to approve a rent
> increase above the guideline if:
>
> - a landlord’s costs for municipal taxes or utilities (heat, water and electricity combined) have increased an exceptional amount,
> - a landlord’s operating costs related to security services increased, or
> - the landlord had eligible capital expenditures, meaning extraordinary or significant renovations, repairs, replacements or new
>   additions to the building or to individual units.

https://www.legalline.ca/legal-answers/rent-increases-and-maximum-rent/

The administrator of my apartment building said a 10% rent increase might be expected for this year, because there's a major renovation on the balcony, windows and doors. Is that legal? It seems like it is legal and they must had permission to increase the rent to that extent, but I am wondering if there's a upper limit or it can be increased to 10, 20 or even 50%

Comment: I assume you are living in/interested in Ontario?

Answer (score 2):

Renting laws are provincial and the rules you cited are for Ontario only.

> It seems like it is legal and they must had permission to increase the rent to that extent.

Unlikely to be true in Ontario. Additionally, they almost certainly did not have a prior permission to increase the rent unless you have ignored many documents from your landlord. If they do want to increase the rent above the guidelines, an application must be made to the Board at least 90 days before the effective date of proposed rent increase. A notice of application must be delivered to the tenant at soon as possible.

The landlord claiming capital expenditures must make relevant documents available to tenants, who have a right to respond to the application before the Board.

More information can be found from the [Board's website](https://tribunalsontario.ca/documents/ltb/Interpretation%20Guidelines/14%20-%20Applications%20for%20Rent%20Increases%20above%20the%20Guideline.html):

> The application MUST be filed at least 90 days before the effective date of the first intended rent increase being claimed in the application. This is called the first effective date (FED).
>
> ...
>
> **Capital Expenditure Information for Tenants**
>
> Where an AGI claims capital expenditures, the landlord must make all the supporting documents and materials available to affected tenants as follows:
>
> - On the request of a tenant subject to the application, the landlord must provide a compact disc containing PDF versions of all the
>   material provided to the LTB for a charge of not more than five
>   dollars, OR
> - the landlord and tenant may agree that the landlord will provide the tenant with either a photocopy of the material for no more than the
>   landlord's reasonable out-of-pocket costs for the photocopying or an
>   email attaching PDF versions of the materials, at no charge to the
>   tenant.
> - If a landlord has not provided the LTB with a compact disc because it qualifies for an exemption from this requirement, the landlord
>   must, on the tenant's request, provide the tenant with a photocopy of
>   the materials for a charge of not more than five dollars.
> - If the landlord has an office in or close to the residential complex, the landlord must, during normal business hours and at no
>   charge, make a photocopy of the materials available for viewing by
>   tenants.
>
> In the application the landlord must inform every tenant subject to the application of the ways in which a tenant may obtain access to the materials filed with the application.
>
> ...
>
> **Written or Oral Hearing?**
>
> The LTB will review the complete application and may decide that the issues can be decided in a written hearing. If this happens the LTB will issue a Notice of Written Hearing which the landlord must give to the tenants within 20 days. Applications seeking an AGI due to an extraordinary increase in municipal taxes and charges and applications seeking an AGI due to operating costs related to security services are usually scheduled for a written hearing.
>
> A tenant may file a written response, including supporting documents, within 50 days from the date the LTB issues the Notice of Written Hearing. The response does not need to be delivered to the landlord or the other tenants. The landlord may file a reply to the tenants' response no later than 65 days after the Notice of Written Hearing is issued.
>
> An application seeking an AGI based on capital expenditures is usually scheduled for an oral (in person) hearing.

There are also many other rules on the eligibility of capital expenditures

> but I am wondering if there's a upper limit or it can be increased to 10, 20 or even 50%

In Ontario, there is a 3% limit for exceptional rent increases related to capital expenses.

> **3% Limitation**
>
> The maximum annual increase allowed in an application based on capital expenditures or security services or both is 3% above the guideline. Where more than 3% is justified, the rent is increased by 3% in the first year and any remaining increase may be taken in subsequent years, to a maximum of two additional years at 3% each year.
>
> The 3% limitation does not apply where the application is based on an increase in the cost of municipal taxes and charges. Where an increase is justified by these categories, the landlord may take the entire increase in the first year.

Comment: "Renting laws are provincial": are there never municipal laws or regulations?  There are in some US municipalities (where most renting law is similarly established by the states), mostly in large cities as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @phoog It would also depend on the province. In BC it is allowed to some extent, since BC's enabling statutes for certain municipalities give cities control over rentals and does not consider bylaws invalid if it is possible to follow both provincial and municipal laws.

Comment: But some other provinces like Ontario consider municipal bylaws invalid if it frustrates the purpose of provincial laws, for which could be argued that provincial RTAs aim to be a comprehensive regulatory scheme that excludes application of bylaws that touches what's been regulated in RTA (but may be valid for related matters like airbnb regulations or business licensing or zoning related restrictions or building code or health code enforcements that are not directly regulated by a comprehensive provincial law and have explicit legal bases within municipal powers).

Comment: In the case of NYC, I think there are some provisions of L&T law that are enacted by the state but apply only to NYC.